# Need Help Building APK from Python Script in Google Colab with Buildozer

Tags: python, build, kivy, apk, google-colaboratory

I have a Python script that works flawlessly when executed in a Python environment, displaying the expected UI with a button and label. However, I'm encountering difficulties when trying to compile it into an Android APK using Buildozer within Google Colab.

To address this issue, I've made sure to use the most up-to-date installations in Colab, but to troubleshoot, I began by simplifying my initial app (which is not provided here) to the basic app included in this post. My intention was to start with the basics and gradually expand the functionality. However, even with this basic app that I'm sharing here, I'm unable to compile it successfully. I suspect that the problem lies in the buildozer.spec file, which I'm also sharing in this post.

I'm seeking assistance and insights from the community to identify and resolve the issues I'm facing in compiling my Python Kivy script into an APK using Buildozer in Google Colab. Any guidance on troubleshooting the buildozer.spec file would be greatly appreciated.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

# Main Screen Class
class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

# Screen Manager
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

# Main Application Class
class BasicApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()

# Main execution of the application
if __name__ == '__main__':
    BasicApp().run()


# buildozer.spec

[app]

title = Basic Kivy App
package.name = basicapp
package.domain = net.aesencryptornl
source.dir = .
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas
requirements = python3,kivy
version = 0.1
orientation = portrait

[buildozer]

log_level = 2
warn_on_root = 1

[buildozer.android]

fullscreen = 0
android.api = 30
android.minapi = 21
android.ndk = 19b
android.sdk = 24
android.entrypoint = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity
android.manifest.theme = @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar
android.update_sdk = True
android.javac_target = 1.8

# commands I used in Google Colab 

# Install Buildozer
!pip install buildozer

# Install Cython (Version 3.0.6 used, originally tried cython==0.29.19)
!pip install cython==3.0.6

# Update package lists
!sudo apt-get update

# Install required packages
!sudo apt-get install -y \
    python3-pip \
    build-essential \
    git \
    python3 \
    python3-dev \
    ffmpeg \
    libsdl2-dev \
    libsdl2-image-dev \
    libsdl2-mixer-dev \
    libsdl2-ttf-dev \
    libportmidi-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    zlib1g-dev

!sudo apt-get install -y \
    libgstreamer1.0 \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-base \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-good

!sudo apt-get install build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2
!sudo apt-get install libffi-dev

# Upload project files
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

# Build the Android APK with Buildozer
!buildozer -v android debug
```

Comment: Maybe this video can guide you in the right direction. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XqWLaMtDCyk&t=81s&ab_channel=GAURAVKUMARJAIN

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

Change your `Cython` version to `0.29.26` and install the `libtool` package:

```
!pip install cython==0.29.26
!apt-get update
!apt-get install libtool
```

It worked for me on Google Colab.

**Long answer:**

I tested your script on my personal environment and it works great so your buildozer spec file does not need any modification. When I tried on Google Colab however, I had some issues and the script crashed.

When searching for the first crash cause, I found this [github issue](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/1533) for which the fix was to install `libtool`.

I then recompiled but had another crash and I found another [github issue](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/8325) explaining it was because of the Cython version. So I downgraded to the `0.29.19` but it failed on install because of dependencies conflicts. I finally decided to use the same version as on my own computer which is `0.29.26` and everything ran (after a while) flawlessly.

For easier buildozer configuration, I suggest you to use the `buildozer init` command in the future. It will automatically create a prefilled spec file template.

Comment: Correct! downgrading the Cython version worked for me as well.